# AngularJS typeahead giving [filter:notarray] error on Ajax GET query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-ui-typeahead

I have an AngularJS 1.4.7 typeahead:

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control simpleinput"
       placeholder="keyword" 
       name="searchbarFormInput"
       id="searchbarFormInput" 
       ng-model="selected" 
       ng-click="selected=null"
       ng-enter="doBlur($event)"
       uib-typeahead="record.display_name for record in getRecords($viewValue) | filter:{ display_name : $viewValue }"
       typeahead-template-url="searchbar-result-template.html"
       typeahead-on-select="selectRecord($item)"
       typeahead-focus-on-select="false"
       typeahead-editable="false"
       autocomplete="off" />
```

This typeahead's controller calls `getRecords(needle)` and filters on the provided `needle` value (`$viewValue`, or whatever value is in the `input` view):

```
$scope.getRecords = function(needle) {
    return $scope.testRecords;
}
```

Here, `$scope.testRecords` is an array of test objects, e.g.:

```
$scope.testRecords = [ { "display_name" : "foo" } , { "display_name" : "bar" } ... ];
```

This works correctly. The typeahead will render a pulldown menu. The menu is filtered based on what I type into the `input` field.

Now I want to source this array of records from a GET query:

```
$scope.getRecords = function(needle) {
    return $http.get('/search/by', {
        params: {
            'requestType' : 'searchByDisplayName',
            'pageSize' : 1000
        }
    }).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.data.results);
        return res.data.results;
    });
}
```

This is a GET request to a route that works when called directly (confirmed via, for example, `curl` or `wget`).

Also, when I look at the browser console, `console.log(res.data.results)` shows the correct array of objects — the exact same objects that are in the array `$scope.testObjects`.

However, I get no pulldown menu and I also get the following `[filter:notarray]`  error:

```
Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%22%24%24state%22%3A%7B%22status%22%3A0%7D%7D
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:6:421
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:149:197
fn
R@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js:11:6694
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js:11:8633
$$parseAndValidate@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:263:425
$commitViewValue@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:263:284
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:265:279
$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:133:221
$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:133:456
$$debounceViewValueCommit@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:265:249
$setViewValue@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:264:507
l@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:163:165
c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:35:221
```

This error repeats for as many letters as I enter into the `input` field.

What am I doing wrong with the request, typeahead, or typeahead filter, and how can I fix this?

Comment: do cross check that object return is of type `array` or not, I think you should also look into [this github issue](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1710)

Comment: If I log the following: `console.log(res.data.results instanceof Array);` I get `true` back on each keypress.

Comment: Did you went through the github issue link which I gave..

Comment: The object I am returning — `res.data.results` — is an instance of an `Array`, so I'm not sure how the Github issue you linked explains the issue, unless there is a specific comment I missed which is unrelated to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code that doesn't work you're returning a promise (the result of .then()), not the array:

```
res.data.results
```

**Edit:**
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js#L219

Expects the result of the expression to yield an array and not a promise. In other words, you should use the change event to trigger the function that updates your array via a promise, but the 'for record in nameOfAnArray' portion of the expression should not be the function. It should be a variable on the $scope. When it changes it should trigger the digest and update.

Comment: what do you mean? this is how `uib-typeahead` directive expect, it deals with promise and when data comes up, it assign it to the list options..

Comment: I didn't vote you down but I'm not sure I understand your answer. Thanks for answering. Can you please elaborate, if you have time?